# List items need a full width top border if they break into two lines

Tags: html, css, list

I have a challenge with a menu of list items. The designer wants to add a line above the items if they break into two lines (in smaller screens). The line should span 100% of the ul width, even though the the second line of list items are shorter. It should look like this image - only with the grey line above the list items.

[image]

I have [fiddled with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y3ejhy/3/) trying to use a `:pseudo element`, but still no luck in getting the grey line of the second row take up 100% of the width.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using a table here (or using divs with display:table-cell etc.) - it looks like you are using tabular data?

Comment: Well, it's not tabular data - it's a menu. A menu built inside the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: How is it suppposed look if it doesn't break into more than one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution sis to make the pseudo-element ***really*** big.

```
li:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

> The designer wants to add a line above the items if they break into two lines (in smaller screens).

Note: Since CSS can't detect line breaking this would *always* apply..so you'd have to apply this in a media query.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
li:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
div {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```